# How to copy values from a sheet to another if values matches?

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy some values to another sheet if the values match each other.

The first sheet:

The second sheet:

And what I want to do is: On the 2nd sheet, if the name "ABEL ALVES PAIVA" is on the 1st sheet in COLUMN A it should return all the information from it (all the row).

I did that by hand, but I have a lot of information (100k rows). This should be returned on 3rd sheet.

I already tried lookup and match formulas but I couldn't get it to work:

```
=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$886863,1,FALSE)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the formula you tried, and any errors?

Comment: @BruceWayne =VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$886863,1,FALSE)
but probably im doing that very wrong lol

Comment: FYI, it is better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59722331/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$886863,5,FALSE)`, you need to change the `1` to be the column you want to return. Currently it'd just return the `NomeRequest`

Comment: @BruceWayne well... after i tested it, i see that that function only returns to me the nº of row where it finds a match... it doesnt copy every row.

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(D5,Sheet1!$A$2:$G$886863,5,FALSE
```

Did the trick for me. 5 is the column i want to return.

I want to thank to @BruceWayne for the help.